# Validation Error on Inbound Change Set - What am I missing?

Tags: apex, visualforce, deployment, change-set

I'm getting Validation Error on Inbound Change Set for this page, but I've tried both closures it asks for and I get the same error every time when promoting to prod.

> Element type "input" should be followed by either attribute
> specifications, ">" or "/>" in LogACall at line 355

```
  [354]  <apex:column width="10%">
  [355]  <apex:actionSupport action="{!setPlaceID}" event="onclick" reRender="CallDetails,CallDetailsSection,CallItemSection" status="statusProcessing"> 
  [356] <div style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">
  [357]    <input type="radio" name="SelectedAddress" value="{!a1.typ}" {!a1.isSelect}/>
  [359] </div>
  [360]  </apex:actionSupport>
  [361]  </apex:column>
```

Comment: Did you try to add the closing tag for the input element? <input></input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes its hard to see the woods through the trees, but my guess is you are missing the checked attribute ;)

<input type="radio" name="SelectedAddress" value="{!a1.typ}" **checked="**{!a1.isSelect}**"**/>